# Merging dataframes and duplicating similar ID values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have two dataframes of different sizes that I am trying to merge while duplicating one the elements of the shorter list to match the shape of the larger dataframe.

- One dataframe has a column of filenames followed by columns of annotations (0 for no, 1 for yes). This dataframe may contain duplicate username values.
- The other dataframe has a column of filenames and a column of text strings.

```
print(df1)

    Filename       Animal      Place      Food

0   user1.txt        1           0          0
1   user1.txt        0           0          1
2   user2.txt        0           1          0
3   user2.txt        0           0          1
4   user3.txt        1           0          0


print(df2)

    Filename                        Text  

0   user1.txt        "These cows make for a great steak"  
1   user2.txt        "Italy has the best pasta" 
2   user3.txt        "Sharks are my favorite animal"
```

What I'd would like to do is merge the 2 dataframes on filename, but if df1 has duplicate "Filename" values, keep the corresponding text value for that "Filename". So for instance the final dataframe would look like this:

```
    Filename       Animal      Place      Food     

0   user1.txt        1           0          0        "These cows make for a great steak" 
1   user1.txt        0           0          1        "These cows make for a great steak"
2   user2.txt        0           1          0        "Italy has the best pasta"
3   user2.txt        0           0          1        "Italy has the best pasta"
4   user3.txt        1           0          0        "Sharks are my favorite animal"
```

If anyone has any ideas, I'd appreciate some help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df3 = pd.merge(A, B, left_on='Filename', right_on='Filename')
```

Now, `df3` is your goal dataframe.

Comment: Yep, you were right. Thanks for the help, I appreciate it.